# Function to replace placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, placeholder

We've created a function to work as a substitute for placeholder text in fields, that should run if the browser hasn't support for the placeholder attribute (i.e early IE browsers).

However, it doesn't seem to work and we can't figure out the reason. Could you see what's wrong?

```
setup_placeholders = (function() {
    $.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) {
        $.support.placeholder = true;
        return function() {}
    } else {
        return function(){
            $(function() {
                var active = document.activeElement;
                $('form').delegate(':text', 'focus', function () {
                    var _placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder'),
                        _val = $(this).val();
                    if (_placeholder != '' && _val == _placeholder) {
                        $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
                    }
                }).delegate(':text', 'blur', function () {
                    var _placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder'),
                        _val = $(this).val();

                    if (!_placeholder && ( _val == '' || _val == _placeholder)) {
                        $(this).val(_placeholder).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
                    }
                }).submit(function () {
                    $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
                });
                $(':text').blur();
                $(active).focus();
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

JQuery approach :

```
(function($) {
    var safe = [];
    $.fn.store = function() {
        safe[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        $(this).click(function() {if ($(this).val() == safe[$(this).attr('id')]) $(this).val('');});
        $(this).blur(function() {if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(safe[$(this).attr('id')]);});
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Usage :

```
<input type="text" id="txt_field" name="txt_field" value="Placeholder">
<script>
    $('#txt_field').store();
</script>
```